# Hartree Fock for an atom (Beryllium)?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, theoretical-chemistry, basis-set

I'm working on solution of Hartree-Fock equation for Beryllium in configuration $1s^2 2s^2$, expanding the orbital with STO-3G basis
$$\phi_k=\sum_{p=0}^3 C_{kp}e^{-\alpha_{kp}r^2}$$
I know the values of $\alpha_k$ both for 1s and 2s.
All books speak about solving molecules and the only case with atom is the helium case, so I have some doubts. In molecular case they expand the molecular orbital as
$$\phi_k=\sum_{p} C_{kp}\chi_p$$
without index $k$ on $\chi_p$ and so also all matrices I need to solve the eigenvalue problem. For this reason I can't understand the difference between the basis set used in molecular case and atom case and consequently how to solve the Fock equation in the case of an atom, and in particular of Beryllium.

Comment: Your definitions of $\phi_k$ and $\chi_p$ are unclear, but maybe that's part of your confusion? If your first equation is correct, then $\phi_k$ are the AOs. But the second equations looks like $\phi_k$ are MOs and $\chi_p$ are AOs. That doesn't add up. Please double check what those are supposed to be.

Comment: Exactly! That's the part of my confusion! In the case of a molecule I expand my MOs as combinations of AOs and for closed shells I find Roothaan equation (that's what books treat and what I understood). But in the case of a simple atom, like beryllium, what happens?

Comment: Formally, the very same thing. But the result may be that the MO coefficient matrix becomes the identity matrix, so MOs equal AOs. But this depends on your AO basis set of course.

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea of the form of the matrices in the case of beryllium. In fact my book expand each MOs with a given basis and then create the Fock and overlap matrix. In my case I have an expansion of each AO with ITS OWN STO-3G basis and I don't know how to use the expression for the Fock and overlap matrix given.

Comment: The matrices in HF (Overlap, Fock etc.) are in the basis of AOs, not the actual basis functions. Whether you choose STO-3G, STO-6G, or maybe even actual Slater type orbitals does not matter for those matrices. This will affect how the AOs look like, and therefore indirectly the numbers in those matrices. But the matrices itself only depend AOs and do not care about the basis function the AOs are expaned in. If you only have 1s and 2s orbitals, then these matrices will be of dimensions $2\times 2$ (using a minimal basis, no p orbitals and spatial orbitals).

Comment: Ok, maybe now it's clear. So in the case of beryllium I have the following expansion in HF $\phi_k=\sum_p C_{kp}\chi_p$, where the index $p$ stands for $1s$ or $2s$. This expansion does not care about the fact that both 1s and 2s AOs (that are represented by $\chi_p$) are expanded into STO-3G basis. So my matrices in Fock equations are in the beginning $2 x 2$, since I have two AOs, but the single elements in those $2 x 2$ matrices are in reality $3 x 3$ blocks due to the expansion of single orbitals in STO-3G basis. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, except for the $3\times 3$ blocks part. When you perform the integrals of the AOs, then you get 3  primitive Gaussians in both, bra and ket vector. Expanding this product of sums yields 3*3=9 primitive products, which all are summed into the final $2\times 2$ matrix element. You may however first calculate all the primitive Integrals and keep them in a $6 \times 6$ matrix, which you then transform to the $2\times 2$ one. See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76323/how-to-compute-2-electron-integral-for-hartree-fock-code/76460